# ushort equivalent

Tags: c#, java, types, ushort

I have an application in C# that I'm trying to convert to java. The C# app has a few variables that are of type ushort. Is there an equivalent in java?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest equivalent in terms of size is `char`, since Java doesn't have unsigned types, but it's overloaded in Java to provide additional semantics related to individual characters. In general, just pick the next largest integral type (`int`, in this case). (**[You're not the only one](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4504839)** who wants it, though.)

Answer (score 1):

As you may be aware, Java [has no unsigned numbers](http://skeletoncoder.blogspot.com/2006/09/java-tutorials-why-no-unsigned.html). This means you're going to have to go with another solution. It's generally easiest to just use the next larger type in cases like these, such as `int` (which is simply a 32-bit signed integer).